# Area of sector form

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, area

[image]

Suppose I have the following sector form with radius $1$,  with $60°$. I divide the sector form into three pieces with an equal degree $(20°)$ and connect four points in the picture and try to calculate the area.

How one can compute the area without calculus?

---

My first guess was using $A=\frac{1}{2}r^2θ$ and try to decompose the figures into triangles and small sector forms. But at some points I lost. Actually via equations of circle and computing intersection points and do integration I compute the area but I think that was too harsh.

Comment: Do you consider using $A=\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$ as calculus?

Comment: @SarGe. My first guess was using $A=\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$.  And try to decompose the figures into triangles and small sector forms. 

But at some points I lost. Actually via equations of circle and computing intersection points and do integration I compute the area but I think that was too harsh.

Comment: Start with a much easier geometry. Take a quarter of a circle and cut it with an angle $\theta$. Draw the red line from the end point of this cut, to the horizontal edge of the geometry. How much area is there above this red line? Start by doing this and then add more details to the computation ...

Comment: $ \frac{ \pi r^2 }{18}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Hint:** The area of the unknown region is given as $$\text{Area}(\text{sector}\ CDE)-\text{Area}(\triangle EHD)+\text{Area}(\square FCHG)$$

Note that $\square FCHG$ is a trapezium. Coordinates of the point $H$ are $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\sin20°\cdot\cos40°}{\sin40°},\sin20°\right)$.