# How to calculate the coordinates on an arc that divides it into five equal parts?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a circle sector for which I know:

**The coordinates of the three points $A, B$, and $S$, and the radius of circle $S$.**

[image]

I've worked on something similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716972/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-the-center-of-the-arc), but it was midpoint coordinates.

Now I need $4$ points to "divide" the arc into five equal parts. How do I calculate it, please?

Thank you.

PS. I calculated the midpoint coordinates using a vector (it's written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3717063/799183))

Comment: With an arc of a circle there is no problem: you have to divide the corresponding angle into five equal parts and calculate the corresponding intersections one by one.

Comment: @yoda666, I've answered a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3794874/782505) for three equal parts.

Comment: @yoda666: radial lengths SA=SB? If so, center of arc S and only one of A,B needs to be given along with a central angle.

Answer (score 1):

First, determine the angle of the entire arc, i.e., $\alpha = \measuredangle ASB$. For this, calculate the perpendicular, i.e., shortest, distance from $A$ to $SB$. This is given by the formula for the distance to a [line defined by two points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points), where with $r = \sqrt{(y_2 - y_3)^2 + (x_2 - x_3)^2}$ is the radius of the circle, we get:

$$p = \frac{\left|(y_2 - y_3)x_1 - (x_2 - x_3)y_1 + x_2y_3 - y_2x_3\right|}{r} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If the point where this perpendicular meets $SB$ is $C$, the $\triangle ACS$ is right-angled at $C$, so we then get

$$\sin(\alpha) = \frac{p}{r} \implies \alpha = \arcsin\left(\frac{p}{r}\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note, however, the determined value of $\alpha$ assumes $\measuredangle ASB \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. However, with $SA$ being perpendicular to $SB$, there are $2$ points where $A$ can be which gives the same value of $\alpha$ and, otherwise, there are $4$ possible points, as indicated in the diagram below.

[image: Showing 4 possible places where B can be based to give the same value of alpha]

Note $\measuredangle A_1SB = \alpha$, $\measuredangle A_2SB = \pi - \alpha$, $\measuredangle A_3SB = \pi + \alpha$ and $\measuredangle A_4SB = 2\pi - \alpha$.  If there are bounds or other conditions allowing you to already know which one is correct, e.g., $\measuredangle ASB \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ so $A$ is $A_1$ and the angle is $\alpha$, then you can just use that angle. Otherwise, there are several ways to determine which point, and thus angle, is the correct one. Here is a relatively simple method to use.

The vector $\mathbf{v_1}$ going from $S$ to $B$ is

$$\mathbf{v_1} = (x_2 - x_3, y_2 - y_3) = (x_4, y_4) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Let $\theta_i$ for $1 \le i \le 4$ be each of the $4$ possible values of $\measuredangle A_{i}SB$ given above, and the vector from $S$ to $A_{i}$ be $\mathbf{v_{2,i}}$. Then the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) formula gives

$$\mathbf{v_{2,i}} = (x_4\cos(\theta_i) - y_4\sin(\theta_i), x_4\sin(\theta_i) + y_4\cos(\theta_i)) = (x_{5,i}, y_{5,i}) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

which means

$$A_i = (x_3 + x_{5,i}, y_3 + y_{5,i}) = (x_{6,i}, y_{6,i}) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Due to errors, usually quite small, in the determined trigonometric values and rounding errors in the calculations, it's likely none of the $A_i$ values will match those of $A$ exactly. You can use something like checking the absolute values of the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates being very close or, alternatively, determine the smallest distance using

$$d_i = \sqrt{(x_{6,i} - x_1)^2 + (y_{6,i} - y_1)^2} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Once the appropriate $\theta_i$ angle is determined, the first arc point $D$ to determine is a rotation of $\mathbf{v_1}$ by an angle of $\beta = \frac{\theta_{i}}{5}$, so let the vector from $S$ to $D$ be $\mathbf{v_3}$. The rotation formula then gives

$$\mathbf{v_{3}} = (x_4\cos(\beta) - y_4\sin(\beta), x_4\sin(\beta) + y_4\cos(\beta)) = (x_{7}, y_{7}) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

which means

$$D = (x_3 + x_{7}, y_3 + y_{7}) \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

You can use a similar procedure for the other $3$ arc points to determine.

Comment: @yoda666 I realized it works only if $\measuredangle ASB \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. This might always be the situation for you but, in case it's not plus for anybody else who might read this and want to use it for situations there the angle is larger, I've updated my answer for it to handle the other possibilities. I'm sorry I didn't think of and handle that maximum angle limitation earlier.

Comment: Nothing happened. I understand that my image gives the impression that the angle won't be higher than 90°. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Write $s=x_3+i y_3$, compute the radius $r=((x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2)^{1/2}$, compute $\theta_0 = \text{atan} \frac{y_2-y_3}{x_2-x_3}$, and $\theta_1=\text{atan} \frac{y_1-y_3}{x_1-x_3}.$

Now $b=s+re^{i\theta_0}$ and $a=s+re^{i\theta_1}.$

The four points are $s+re^{i[\theta_0 + \frac{k}{5} (\theta_1-\theta_0)]},\quad k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: Right, $e$ is euler's constant, and in Euler's identity:  $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, the symbol $i$ is the square root of minus one:  $i=\sqrt{-1}.$

Comment: OK. I just want to ask you, please, what if the angle was 90 degrees, specifically would x1 = x3? In that case, wouldn't a **θ1** be able to calculate, because it can't be divided by zero.

Comment: Well, $\lim_{\theta\to \frac{\pi}{2}} \tan \theta = \infty$, so you are right, the denominator $x_1-x_3$ would be zero and you would have $\arctan \infty$.  From the context, we could understand this to be $\frac{\pi}{2} = 90^\circ.$